# SonarQube and SourceMeter Excluding All Source Files

Tags: python, sonarqube

I stumbled upon SourceMeter when looking for a python static code analyzer and I am pretty impressed with the output. I am now trying to integrate the SourceMeter output with the SonarQube interface using the SourceMeter plugin.

However, when I try to run a SonarQube (sonar-runner) analysis on my Python project using the SourceMeter plugin, it excludes all of my source files. Part of the output is located below. This happens if I run the analysis through the Eclipse plugin or through the command line. It just doesn't want to include those files, even if I explicitly tell it to include them.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
13:14:03.944 INFO  - Base dir: C:\Users\cbreinga\workspace\Password-Reset-Utility
13:14:03.944 INFO  - Working dir: C:\Users\cbreinga\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\Password-Reset-Utility\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core
13:14:03.944 INFO  - Source paths: src
13:14:03.944 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
13:14:03.944 INFO  - Index files
13:14:03.945 INFO  - Excluded sources: 
13:14:03.945 INFO  -   **/PyUnitTests/**/*
13:14:03.945 INFO  -   **/src/GUI/PopUpWindowCantClose.py
13:14:03.945 INFO  -   **/src/Util/Killer.py
13:14:03.945 INFO  -   **/src/GUI/ProgressPanel.py
13:14:03.945 INFO  -   **/src/GUI/OptionsPanel.py
...
13:14:05.000 INFO  - 0 files indexed
13:14:05.001 INFO  - Quality profile for python: SourceMeter way
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/) for Python can be used by simply invoking it on a directory containing the Python source modules. The analysis works as follows:

- If the directory contains an __init__.py file, SourceMeter analyzes the given directory (i.e. a python package) recursively while it founds a corresponding __init__.py file in the appropriate sub-directories.
- If the directory does not contain an __init__.py file, SourceMeter checks all the first level sub-directories of the given directory and analyzes each of them containing an __init__.py file recursively (like in the above case).
- In order to analyze python files not forming a python package, an empty __init__.py file needs to be added to the analysis directory.

In case your sonar properties file is not placed next to the __init__.py of the top level python module and it does not find any __init__.py files in the subdirectories it will not analyze any files. So please make sure you place the sonar properties file to the right place (i.e. next to the top level python module's __init__.py file).

Comment: The issue was that I didn't have a __init__ in my src folder. Using the eclipse plugin, it runs the analysis from the project root directory, and seems to ignore the "sonar.sources" value. I was expecting the behavior of running the analysis from the directories listed in sources. Thus, it would have found my source files in the packages below the src directory because they all have __init__ files.